# MySQL8 replication error: When @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is set to a GTID, you must explicitly set it to a different value after a COMMIT or ROLLBACK

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, replication

I struggle with Mysql replication error as follow.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                           
- CHANNEL_NAME:
- WORKER_ID: 1
- THREAD_ID: NULL
- SERVICE_STATE: OFF
- LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 1837
- LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'a057ace9-c959-11ed-af37-0a7c3345f441:271156' at master log mysql-bin-changelog.011219, end_log_pos 87830; Error executing row event: 'When @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is set to a GTID, you must explicitly set it to a different value after a COMMIT or ROLLBACK. Please check GTID_NEXT variable manual page for detailed explanation. Current @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT is 'xxx-xxx-xxxxx:xxxx'.'                                 
-  LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 2023-05-08 07:36:30.502664
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION: xxx-xxx-xxxxx:xxxx
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 2023-05-08 07:36:30.497622
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_END_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 2023-05-08 07:36:30.499189
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION: xxx-xxx-xxxxx:xxxx
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 2023-05-08 07:36:30.499213
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
- LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
- APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                                          
1.  CHANNEL_NAME:
1. WORKER_ID: 2
1. THREAD_ID: NULL
1. SERVICE_STATE: OFF
1. LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_END_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. 3. row ***************************
1. CHANNEL_NAME:
1. WORKER_ID: 3
1. THREAD_ID: NULL
1. SERVICE_STATE: OFF
1. LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_END_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. 4. row ***************************
1. CHANNEL_NAME:
1. WORKER_ID: 4
1. THREAD_ID: NULL
1. SERVICE_STATE: OFF
1. LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_END_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
1. APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
1. 4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

/var/log/mysqld.log also said the same error without any specific info...

The replication configuration is that AWS RDS(Mysql5.7) is Master, and Mysql8.0.3 on EC2 as slave.
Using GTID repl and Everything had been well for 1 week without no error and stop. However, all of sudden Slave_SQL_Running: says "NO"...
Through this error, I did some setting like,

1. slave stop.
2. SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT = 'AUTOMATIC' and slave start.
3. slave start;

This act didnt work. and i checked mysql-bin-changelog.011219 outputs and here are.

```
# The proper term is pseudo_replica_mode, but we use this compatibility alias
# to make the statement usable on server versions 8.0.24 and older.
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;
```

I cant tell exactly what is been wrong... anything i missed something?